# How to get Values of a Column without circles in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ado.net

i have a table in sql server. i want to get values of a specific column without circle. I can do this with this code. but it make a big interval like 2 hours.
My problem is time. :(

```
for (int i = 1; i <= tedadSatrFrequentItemsetTable; i++)
        {
            string sql1 = "select F01 from Chess.dbo.Sheet1$ where ID= " + i;

            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);
            SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            rdr1.Read();
            tedadTekrar[i] = Convert.ToInt16(rdr1.GetValue(0));

            conn.Close();

            if (tedadTekrar < astane)
                ++tedadItemsetGomShodeh;
        }
```

i want save this in a array in my program in c#.

Comment: by circles I guess you mean iterations or DB round trips?

Comment: @alex.feigin i want some thing like that
int[] tedadTekrar = new int[200];
tedadTekrar = rdr1.GetValue(0);

Answer (score 2):

How about you avoid the loop and count the rows in the query?

```
select 
    tedadItemsetGomShodeh = count(*) 
from 
    Chess.dbo.Sheet1$ 
where 
    ID between 1 and @tedadSatrFrequentItemsetTable 
    and F01 < @astane
```

Comment: i want this column in c#, not sql server

Comment: give me a way to save this in a array in c#

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query to get them all at once.

```
select F01 from Chess.dbo.Sheet1$ where ID <= tedadSatrFrequentItemsetTable
```

Comment: i want this column in c#, not sql server.